# Javascript class setter on each attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, metaprogramming

I am trying to create a class that has a number of objects assigned as attributes. I am stuck on implementing setters on these attributes.

Failing example below. When I do `record1.foo = 'bar'; // record.foo is now a string` I overwrite the attribute with a string, rather than set the value inside the Element class.

Hope this makes sense, I would like a setter to write the value into the Element rather than replace it.

```
'use strict';

const assert = require('chai').assert;

class Element {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = null;
  }

  getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

  setValue(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  toString() {
    return this.getValue();
  }

}

class Record {

  constructor() {
    this.fields = ['name', 'age', 'foo'];
    this.fields.forEach((field) => {
      this[field] = new Element(field);
    });
  }

  setValue(field, value) {
    this[field].setValue(value);
  }

  getValue(field) {
    return this[field].getValue();
  }

}

let record1 = new Record();
record1.name.setValue('Bob');
record1.setValue('age', 42);

assert.equal(record1.getValue('name'), 'Bob');
assert.equal(record1.age, 42);

console.log('so far so good');

record1.foo = 'bar'; // record.foo is now a string
assert.equal(record1.getValue('foo'), bar);
```

Comment: Yes, a `setValue` method is not the same as a setter property.

Comment: You want `get value` and `set value` not `getValue` and `setValue`. Nor is it at all clear here what you're trying to do, or how, or why.

Comment: @Bergi - I would like users of the class to be able to use Record.setValue(field, value) or to set directly with (in my example) record1.foo = 'bar'

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah, sorry - I realise the question is vague. I want to support direct assignment to the Element through record1.foo (rather than replace the attribute with a string value)

Comment: In other words you want e.g. the value and name properties of your instances to be delegated to an element?

Comment: @SimonMorris Hey I could help you do it, but it won't be completely ES6, do you want me to write this functionality?

Comment: In my second to last line of the example. I'm overwriting the attribute foo with a literal string 'bar'. Previously it was an instance of the class Element. I would like to set the value of the Element rather than write over it with a string

Comment: @SimonMorris I understood your question, so that's why I'm telling you that solving this question will imply ES5 code, are you ok with that? If yes, I'll write the functionality bellow.

Comment: @alexscr It will run in a later version of Node, I'm very interested in a ES5 solution to learn

Comment: @SimonMorris Please check the response, but your age is not working, is that intended to be like that?

Comment: You are looking for [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a dynamic way to do it the way you want, try this:

```js
'use strict';

class Element {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = null;
  }

  getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

  setValue(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  toString() {
    return this.getValue();
  }

}

class Record {

  constructor() {
    this.fields = ['name', 'age', 'foo'];
    this.fields.forEach((field) => {
      let element = new Element(field);
      Object.defineProperty(this, field, {
        set: function(value) {
          element.setValue(value);
        },
        get: function() {
          return element;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  setValue(field, value) {
    this[field].setValue(value);
  }

  getValue(field) {
    return this[field].getValue();
  }

}

let record1 = new Record();
record1.name.setValue('Bob');
record1.setValue('age', 42);

console.log(record1.getValue('name') === 'Bob');
console.log(record1.age === 42);

record1.foo = 'bar';
console.log(record1.getValue('foo') === 'bar');
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that is what I was after. With this solution I can set values via direct assignment as well as access methods on the element with ```record1.foo.sayHello()``` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is what you want:

```
class Delegator {
  set foo (a) {
    this._foo.value = a;
  }

  get foo () {
    return this._foo.value;
  }

  constructor () {
    let fields = ['foo', 'value', 'name'];
    fields.forEach(fld => this[`_${fld}`] = new Element(fld));
  }
}

let instance = new Delegator();
instance.foo; // returns Element's value of foo
instance.foo = 'bar'; // sets Element's value to bar
```

Comment: Thank you Jared - I prefer AlexScr solution as it allows me to access the Element methods via ```instance.foo.sayHello()``` (or whatever) whereas your solution the element has an alternate name ```this._foo```. Appreciate your example though